# Exception error when I try to iterate over an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection, `Ages`, which only holds one key: `ages`.

In it I store an array of strings like so:

```
['51', '24', '21', '19', '15']
```

I struggled a bit with how to iterate over it in the template but this is what I found worked. First the HTML:

```
<template name="ageFilter">
  {{#each age}}
    <li>
      {{this}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And the helper:

```
Template.ageFilter.helpers({
  age: function() {
    return Ages.findOne().ages
  }
})
```

This is a rather ugly solution that rests on my having only one object in my database (since I use `findOne()` but it's not a big problem, and it works. The template iterates over the array and outputs it.

There's only one problem: the browser console throws an error!

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ages' of undefined
```

Why is this and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your `age` helper is first called before subscription to your `Ages` publication occurs, therefore the first call(s) to `Ages.findOne()` end(s) up returning nothing. You could check if your `Ages` document has been fetched correctly:

```
Template.ageFilter.helpers({
  age: function() {
    var ageItem = Ages.findOne();
    return (ageItem ? ageItem.ages : null);
  }
});
```

But that's just hacking around the issue. Best approach would be to make sure your template does not get rendered before subscription is done. You could use [iron-router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) and put your subscriptions in `waitOn` for that. For example:

```
Router.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('ages');
    }
});
```

Also, overall you might want to change your design and just put one age value per document in your `Ages` collection, stored in a key like `value` or something. It seems more logical. This way you could do:

```
<template name="ageFilter">
  {{#each ages}}
    <li>
      {{value}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And your helper:

```
Template.ageFilter.helpers({
  ages: function() {
    return Ages.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My subscription gets loaded in Iron Router's `onBeforeAction', sadly out of necessity. (Edit: Actually that was my other subscription, so that would work!) Your last suggestion can't help with this issue, can it? I was on the fence on how to store it, and I'm glad storing it as you said isn't crazy because that would be my preferred method.

Comment: Yes, my last suggestion *would* also solve your displayed console error problem. No ages will be fetched at first, no `<li>` will be displayed, but no error in the console. Until, of course, your subscription catches up, then your ages will appear automatically :) it should look instantaneous.

Comment: Oh, that's a relief, because switching the subscription to `waitOn` didn't work. :( Is there something inherently wrong about chaining `ages` on the `find()`?

Comment: Well yes, you should not get a key value directly on a call to some function if you are not sure that this function will return an object. In your case, `Ages.findOne()` can return either an object or `undefined`, therefore it is not wise to ask for its `ages` value right away. Even if you waited for subscription actually! Because you never know if one day your collection will be empty.